# Android - RadioButtons squishing up in RadioGroup - formatting issues

Tags: java, android, xml, radio-button

I am trying to split a `TableRow` into 4 equal sections.  The first is a `TextView`, and the last three are `RadioGroups`.  I have successfully split the `TableRow` into these equal sections.  But, each row is dynamically built, and could possibly have up to 5 `RadioButtons` per `RadioGroup`.  When building a `TableRow` with 5 `RadioButtons` in each `RadioGroup` everything displays and functions, but the `RadioButtons` are squished together.  Is there some way to have the `RadioGroup` have multiple lines when this happens, but still remain in the same section of the same `TableRow`? Basically like a `TextView` will become multiline when given the proper parameters?

Java code for this case:

```
RadioButton rb1, rb2, rb3, rb4, rb5;
RadioGroup rg;
TextView tv;
TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) this.findviewById(R.string.tl);
LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();

//set up TableRow and TextView
TableRow tr = (TableRow)inflater.inflate(R.layout.tablerow3q, tl, false);
tr.setBackgroundColor(Color.LTGRAY);
tv = (TextView)tr.findViewById(R.id.tv);
tv.setText("Some text");

//loop sets up 1 RadioGroup per increment, each with 5 RadioButtons
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    rb1 = new RadioButton(this);
    rb2 = new RadioButton(this);
    rb3 = new RadioButton(this);
    rb4 = new RadioButton(this);
    rb5 = new RadioButton(this);

    rb1.setText("test1");
    rb2.setText("test2");
    rb3.setText("test3");
    rb4.setText("test4");
    rb5.setText("test5");

    //without these layouts, only four buttons are displayed, the other is cut off
    rb1.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rb2.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rb3.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rb4.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);
    rb5.setLayoutParams(new RadioGroup.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1f);

    //add RadioButtons to correct RadioGroup based on loop increment
    if(i == 0) {
        rg1 = (RadioGroup)tr.findViewById(R.id.rg1);
        rg1.addView(rb1);
        rg1.addView(rb2);
        rg1.addView(rb3);
        rg1.addView(rb4);
        rg1.addView(rb5);
    }
    if(i == 1) {
        rg1 = (RadioGroup)tr.findViewById(R.id.rg2);
        rg1.addView(rb1);
        rg1.addView(rb2);
        rg1.addView(rb3);
        rg1.addView(rb4);
        rg1.addView(rb5);
    }
    if(i == 2) {
        rg1 = (RadioGroup)tr.findViewById(R.id.rg3);
        rg1.addView(rb1);
        rg1.addView(rb2);
        rg1.addView(rb3);
        rg1.addView(rb4);
        rg1.addView(rb5);
    }
}
tl.addView(tr);
```

XML layout for `TableRow` that is being inflated:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TableRow xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tv"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg1"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg2"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rg3"
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_margin="1dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.25"
        android:background="#ffffff"/>
</TableRow>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RadioGroup extends LinearLayout, which doesn't wrap its contents. There are a couple of options for dealing with the problem, though:

1. Copy the source code for the `RadioGroup` class and modify it to extend a different type of Layout, such as a `TableLayout` or `RelativeLayout`. You'll need to manage how the radio buttons are arranged.
2. Dynamically build a nested `TableLayout` and use `OnClickListener`s to handle selecting/deselecting the various radio buttons.

Comment: Solved the problem a while back, but suggestion number one is exactly how I did it. Didn't think of the other option, interesting idea.