# RadioGroup : Horizontal layout and Span multiple lines

Tags: android, radio-group

Android 2.3.3

I have around 5 `RadioButton`s in a `RadioGroup`. I don't want the orientation to be vertical as it takes most of the available space. If i keep the orientation to be horizontal, only 2 or 3 will be visible and the rest will disappear as the screen's size doesn't fit them all horizontally.

Can i span these radio buttons in more than 1 line, with the horizontal layout.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can achieve this by wrapping your `RadioGroup` in a `HorizontalScrollView`, and the next radio buttons will appear when the user scrolls to the right.

Comment: Ok, but i want to know if i can get the radiobutton 1 and 2 in a row(if the screen accommodates 2 radiobuttons per row) , and then 3 and 4 in the next and 5th in the third row?

Comment: Not possible with actual `RadioGroup` because it extends a `LinearLayout`. A solution is to create your own `RadioGroup`, see explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/a/12556598/231417

Comment: How will user know that there is actually a HorizontalScrollView there? There should be some remark or alert that user can scroll horizontally ...

Answer (score 3):

A simple way is to use this library:
https://github.com/linfaxin/MultiRowsRadioGroup

Define your XML like this:

```
 <com.linfaxin.multirowsradiogroup.MultiRowsRadioGroup
    android:id="@+id/radioGroup1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:text="radioGroup1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">
        <RadioButton
            android:text="text2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <RadioButton
            android:text="text3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <RadioButton
        android:text="text4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</com.linfaxin.multirowsradiogroup.MultiRowsRadioGroup>
```

Comment: Yeah..., I am not sure if this is what OP wanted, but this does not "wrap" radio buttons; it just allows you to define fixed multiple rows.

Answer (score 0):

One possible solution could be making the radio group multi line.
As Radio Group extends LinearLayout,so radio buttons could be placed only in one direction.

To make radio buttons in a single RadioGroup multiline i've improvised the class by extending it with TableLayout so I can put them in the form of rows and columns while they adhered to Radio group properties.

Here is a solution that worked for me. (java class named `TableRadioGroup`)

```
    public class TableRadioGroup extends TableLayout {
    private int checkedRadioButtonId = -1;
    private OnCheckedChangeListener onCheckedChangeListener;
    private int maxColumns = -1; // Maximum number of columns (-1 for unlimited)
    private int maxRows = -1;    // Maximum number of rows (-1 for unlimited)

    public TableRadioGroup(Context context) {
        super(context);
    }

    public TableRadioGroup(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public void setMaxColumns(int maxColumns) {
        this.maxColumns = maxColumns;
    }

    public void setMaxRows(int maxRows) {
        this.maxRows = maxRows;
    }

    @Override
    public void addView(View child, int index, ViewGroup.LayoutParams params) {
        if (child instanceof TableRow) {
            int numChildren = ((TableRow) child).getChildCount();
            for (int i = 0; i < numChildren; i++) {
                View view = ((TableRow) child).getChildAt(i);
                if (view instanceof RadioButton) {
                    setupRadioButton((RadioButton) view);
                }
            }
        }
        super.addView(child, index, params);

        // Adjust the number of rows and columns if necessary
        adjustTableLayout();
    }

    private void setupRadioButton(final RadioButton radioButton) {
        if (radioButton == null) {
            return;
        }

        radioButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (checkedRadioButtonId != -1) {
                    setCheckedStateForView(checkedRadioButtonId, false);
                }

                int id = radioButton.getId();
                setCheckedStateForView(id, true);
                checkedRadioButtonId = id;

                if (onCheckedChangeListener != null) {
                    onCheckedChangeListener.onCheckedChanged(TableRadioGroup.this, checkedRadioButtonId);
                }
            }
        });
    }

    private void setCheckedStateForView(int viewId, boolean checked) {
        View checkedView = findViewById(viewId);
        if (checkedView != null && checkedView instanceof RadioButton) {
            ((RadioButton) checkedView).setChecked(checked);
        }
    }

    public void setOnCheckedChangeListener(OnCheckedChangeListener listener) {
        onCheckedChangeListener = listener;
    }

    public int getCheckedRadioButtonId() {
        return checkedRadioButtonId;
    }

    public void clearCheck() {
        setCheckedStateForView(checkedRadioButtonId, false);
        checkedRadioButtonId = -1;
    }

    private void adjustTableLayout() {
        if (maxColumns > 0 && maxRows > 0) {
            int childCount = getChildCount();
            int rowCount = 0;
            TableRow currentRow = null;
            for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
                View child = getChildAt(i);
                if (child instanceof TableRow) {
                    currentRow = (TableRow) child;
                    rowCount++;
                } else if (currentRow != null) {
                    int columnCount = currentRow.getChildCount();
                    if (columnCount >= maxColumns) {
                        // Create a new row if the maximum column count is reached
                        if (rowCount < maxRows) {
                            TableRow newRow = new TableRow(getContext());
                            super.addView(newRow, getChildIndex(currentRow) + 1);
                            currentRow = newRow;
                            rowCount++;
                        } else {
                            // Remove extra children that exceed the maximum row count
                            removeView(child);
                            continue;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private int getChildIndex(View child) {
        int childCount = getChildCount();
        for (int i = 0; i < childCount; i++) {
            if (getChildAt(i) == child) {
                return i;
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }

    public interface OnCheckedChangeListener {
        void onCheckedChanged(TableRadioGroup group, int checkedId);
    }
}
```

and this is the xml layout part code snippet where we are displaying our RadioGroup:

```
        <com.antiquelogic.crickslab.Utils.CustomViews.TableRadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/rgActionType"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:maxRows="2">

        <TableRow>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbZero"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="true"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="brilliantEffort"
                android:text="@string/run_0"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textAppearance="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbOne"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="misField"

                android:text="@string/runs_1"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbTwo"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="misField"

                android:text="@string/runs_2"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbThree"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="misField"

                android:text="@string/runs_3"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbFour"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:elevation="@dimen/size_2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="misField"

                android:text="@string/runs_4"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbFive"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:elevation="@dimen/size_2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="misField"

                android:text="@string/runs_5"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

            <RadioButton
                android:id="@+id/rbSix"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginHorizontal="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:layout_marginVertical="@dimen/margin_small"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@drawable/selector_button_new_dashed"
                android:button="@null"
                android:checked="false"
                android:elevation="@dimen/size_2"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:paddingVertical="@dimen/margin_xsmall_8dp"
                android:tag="misField"

                android:text="@string/runs_6"
                android:textAllCaps="true"
                android:textColor="@drawable/text_selector_pop_gray"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:theme="@style/RadioButtonSelectorNew" />

        </TableRow>
    </com.antiquelogic.crickslab.Utils.CustomViews.TableRadioGroup>
```

[image: and this is the final reflection above work in the snapshot.]